# Setting Jetty specific web.xml settings from within WAR

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am in the process of moving to Jetty from another container. I need to set some custom JSP configuration for `JettyJspServlet` etc. I'm doing that via `web.xml`:

```
<servlet id="jsp">
      <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet</servlet-class>
(...)
```

However, these web.xml settings fail for the previous container, and I would like to maintain compatibility for a while.

Is there a way to apply these settings only when the WAR is deployed to Jetty, and not alter Jetty configuration. Thing is I want to set them at WAR packaging level as not to force people to use custom Jetty configuration via jetty.base etc.

I tried setting `overrideDescriptor` to override-web.xml via `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` and while `jetty-web.xml` file is read, the override descriptor seems to be ignored completely.

Comment: What specific things in `JettyJspServlet` are you wanting to configure?  I ask as there's probably an alternate way to configure it without using a formal servlet descriptor.

Comment: Need to disable strictQuoteEscaping.

Comment: Could you use the default descriptor instead?  and set that for all deployed webapps? or is this supposed to only be set for 1 webapp?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Servlet Container and have JSP enabled, you shouldn't be required to use the `<servlet-class>` element, as that would be container specific.

But all Servlet containers that have JSP must expose the named servlet `jsp`, so just rely on the name and configure it without a class.

Change it to just ...

```xml
<servlet id="jsp">
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <!-- no servlet class here -->
  <init-param>
  (...)
```

That should be safe to use on all containers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However the other container is pretty old and doesn't seem to accept id=... syntax, and requires servlet-class.